# Java storing BufferedOutputStream in array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sockets, object

In Java i am trying to store each `BufferedOutputStream` the server makes into an array aside from the threads in order to broadcast some data to all connected clients.

```
// initialisation
   ArrayList<BufferedOutputStream> connections = new ArrayList<BufferedOutputStream>();
// when a client connects
   Socket connection = socket.accept();
   connections[id] = connection;
// broadcasting to all clients
   for (int i = 0; i < connections.size(); i++) {
      try {
         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connections.get(i), "US-ASCII");
         osw.write(s + "\n");
         osw.flush();
      } catch (Exception g) {
         // catch
      }
   }
```

note: only the essential code is given

The problem: The broadcasting loop only broadcasts to the first in the loop, and sometimes the others as well. No error is thrown and the loop iteration as it should.

What is wrong and how do i fix it?
It's probably something obvious but i'm still a beginner..

Thanks!

Comment: What value is given to `id`? And understand that `connections.length` is the length of the array, not the number of initialized elements. Also, you haven't initialized `connections`, only declared it.

Comment: I think connections[id] = connection; is executet before the secound thread create the connection. So connections[id] is probally null. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @JackTools.Net That's exactly it.

Comment: But when placing `connections[id] = connection;` in front of the lines where the thread is started, the thread starts with an empty `connection`. How can i keep the `connection` variable without it getting `null`?

Comment: No, the thread starts with the `connection` value you supplied as a parameter. You need to post more of the code. Your question doesn't make sense at present.

Comment: You can try to change thread = new thread(connection, id); into thread = new thread(connection, id, connections); and put the line connections[id] = connection; into the second thread.

Comment: Please note that i have completely changed the question now.

Comment: You should have opened a new question, all the previous good answers are now obsolete and confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't tell you exactly what is wrong because you've left out important parts of the code.  However, if `connections[id] = connection` is throwing an NPE, that can *only* mean that `connections` is `null`.  And, on the face of it, you don't appear to have initialized `connections` to a non-null value!

The fix is to initialize connections ... somewhere ... to an array of the appropriate size.  However, that brings you other problems.  What is an appropriate size for the array, and what what you are going t when `id` is larger than `connections.length`?

The root problem is an array is (probably) a poor choice for holding the connections ...

Comment: Then what do you suggest me to use in order to hold the connections?

Comment: A Map would probably be best ... if you want to lookup sockets by id.

Comment: I bet that the connections that don't work are throwing exception.  Conveniently (NOT!!) you are *squashing* any exceptions that are thrown in the loop body.  Nice foot shot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the socket has close, or the `i` index in the array is null, so the question is, why don't you utilize the `List<OutputStream>` over `Socket[]`?

with `List<OutputStream>` or `List<OutputStreamWriter>` you will not need to initialize the `OutputStreamWriter` every time you want to send some data.

Answer (score 0):

somehow You should store client socket object.
whenever you want to broadcast, iterate over collection get socket, get ouput stream from that, and write to socket.
Its working for me properly.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: `Socket[] array = new Socket[#];`

You never initialize your array. That could be the problem.
But I suggest using either a `List` or a `Map`.
Apparently, I'm guessing you wanna store the socket in a way that you could retrieve it by a property later (name or ID). In this case, I suggest using a `HashMap`, with `Integer` as they key, and `Socket` as the value. This was, you can use `map.get(ID);`, and it'll return the socket you want.

You could try using a HashMap, maybe have a var for how many people are currently connected.
When someone logs in, do something like

```
public class Serer {

    HashMap<Integer, Socket> list = new HashMap<Integer, Socket>();
    static final int maxConnections = 100;
    static int currentConnections = 0;

    public Server() {
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(/*port#*/, maxConnections);
        }catch(IOException e) { }
    }

    public void acceptConnections() {
        while(currentConnections < maxConnections) {
            list.put(currentConnections++, serversocket.accept());
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket(int ID) {
        return list.get(ID);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().acceptConnections();
    }
```

This isn't tested, and I highly suggest putting the 'acceptConnections' in a thread, so the while loop isn't holding up your code. I didn't catch any exceptions, but hopefully this will give you an idea of using a `HashMap` to hold your sockets

Now, if you wanna send data to all the sockets, you would need to create an `OutputStream` for each socket. I suggest making a class (such as `User.java`), then when someone connects, make a new User, passing it the socket.

```
while(true) {
   new User(ss.accept());
}
```

Then in your `User.java`, have something kind of like:

```
public class User {

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;

    Socket socket;
    public User(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

        initStream();
        startChat();
    }

    public void initStream() {
        try{
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputSTream(socket.getInputStream());
        }catch(IOException e) { }
    }

    public void startChat() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String input;
                try {
                    while((input = (String) in.readObject) != null) {
                        //this loop only triggers when something is retrieved through the input stream

                       Server.sendGlobalMessage(input); //can be done in different ways
                       //The reason why I call this statically from Server.java is because Server.java
                       //is the class that contains the HashMap, but that's up to you of where to put it.
                       //You could make the `HashMap` static, and make the sendGlobalMessage() in User.java
                    }
                }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) { }
            };).start();
    }
```

Now finally for the sendGlobalMessage, you will need to either use an `Iterator`, or you can turn your hashmap into an array. This code is assuming that instead of using a `HashMap` for sockets, you pass the socket into a User class, then use the `HashMap` to store the user. (you need access to the output stream)

```
HashMap<Integer, User> list = new HashMap<Integer, User>();

public static void sendGlobalMessage(String message) {
    for(User user : list.values().toArray(new User[list.size]) {
        try {
            user.out.writeObject(message);
            user.out.flush();
        }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) { }
    }
}
```